# In Vim, Save in normal mode

Tags: normal-mode

I am trying to improve my skill with vim. And I know <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> for to save.

But in *normal mode* the shortcut for <kbd>w</kbd> is for "to the next word".

is there another key for to save quickly? or I need press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>:</kbd>.

Comment: Sounds like the first thing you need to do is get in the habit of making Normal mode your default mode...kind of like your "resting state". That means as soon as you're done entering text hit escape. Every time. Every proficient Vim user does it this way. Then to save you'll usually just need to do `:w` (and Enter of course).

Comment: But in spanish keyboard press " : " is "Shift" + " . " and it is more slow than a one key....that I don't know witch.

Comment: Well for US keyboards `:` is `shift+;`. Pretty much the same effort as yours.

Comment: Yet it is similar in spanish...instead the key . (dot) .

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. Certainly Luc, based on his answer, has a different interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

If you already are in normal mode, you don't need the <kbd>ESC</kbd> part. It's just <kbd>:</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Unlike `ZZ`  for save+quit, I'm not aware of any shortcut to save. It's up to us to map the *save* action to anything of our liking.

My early days with Borland IDEs had me have the following in my `.vimrc`. Others map on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

```
nnoremap <F2> :<c-u>update<CR>
inoremap <F2> <c-o>:update<CR>
vnoremap <F2> <c-c>:update<CR>gv
```

PS: Unlike `:write`, `:update` doesn't `touch` a file that is not modified.